# Как назначить каждой грани SCNBox отдельный материал?

Tags: swift, swift3

Как назначить материал целиком на фигуру - понимаю, но вот как конкретной грани - проблема.

```
// create box geometry
        let boxGeometryOne = SCNBox(width: 4.0, height: 4.0, length: 4.0, chamferRadius: 0.2)

// add box geometry
        boxOne = SCNNode(geometry: boxGeometryOne)

// add box position
        boxOne.position = SCNVector3(x: -2, y: -2, z: -2)

// box materials
        let materialOne = SCNMaterial()
        materialOne.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red

// add material to box
        boxOne.geometry?.firstMaterial = materialOne
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос следующим образом:

```
    // box materials
    let materialOne = SCNMaterial()
    materialOne.diffuse.contents = UIColor.green

    let materialTwo = SCNMaterial()
    materialTwo.diffuse.contents = UIColor.white

    // add material to box
    boxOne.geometry?.materials = [materialOne, materialTwo, materialOne, materialTwo, materialTwo, materialOne]
```